# Yii2. Помогите переделать запрос MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, yii2, запрос, activerecord

Существует работающий в **YII2** через **Product::findBySql()** запрос:

```
SELECT 
`product`.product_name,
`seller`.seller_name,
`city`.city_name,
`street`.street_name,
`address`.address_home 
FROM `product`
LEFT JOIN `seller`  ON `product`.`seller_id`  = `seller` .`id`
LEFT JOIN `address` ON `seller` .`address_id` = `address`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `street`  ON `address`.`street_id`  = `street` .`id`
LEFT JOIN `city`    ON `street` .`city_id`    = `city`   .`id`'
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, переделать его через
**Product::find()**

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = Product::find();
    $query->select('product.product_name, seller.seller_name, city.city_name, street.street_name, address.address_home ')
        ->leftJoin('seller', 'seller.id = product.seller_id')
        ->leftJoin('address', 'address.id = seller.address_id')
        ->leftJoin('street', 'street.id = address.street_id')
        ->leftJoin('city', 'city.id = street.city_id')
        ->all();
```